# Power calculation for binomial test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, statistical-power

I have been asked to do a particular power calculation: We assume that the true probability of an event is 93%. We will do a binomial trial of size N, observe the outcome, and construct a confidence interval for p. If the lower bound of this CI is greater than 0.85, we accept that the true probability of the event is close enough for our purposes to 93%. We want to know the sample size N such that -if the true proportion is indeed 0.93- we have 80% chance of finding the lower bound of the CI greater than 0.85.

Now I would have thought that as the sample size increases, the estimate for p becomes closer to 93%, and the confidence interval becomes narrower, so that the probability of finding a lower limit greater than 0.85 increases. However, this does not appear to be quite the case in a simulation.

My questions are: Why am I seeing this peculiar pattern in the plot, and what can I do to get a monotonic power curve?

Many thanks.

```
#rm(list=ls()) # Uncomment to clear environment
library(ggplot2)
library(binom)

pow <- vector()
Ns <- seq(85,115)
p <- 0.93 # true p
N_SIMS <- 10000

set.seed(1234)
pow  <- cov <-  vector()
for (N in Ns ) {
  print(N)
  lower <- upper <- vector()
  y <- rbinom(N_SIMS,size=N,prob=p)
  for (i in 1:N_SIMS) {
    te <- binom::binom.confint(x=y[i],n=N,conf.level=0.90,methods='agresti-coull')
    lower[i] <- te$lower
upper[i] <- te$upper
    
  }
  pow[N] <- mean(lower>0.85)
  cov[N] <- mean(lower<= p & upper >= p)
}


df <- data.frame(pow=pow,N=seq(1,max(Ns)),coverage=cov)
df <- df[which(!is.na(df$pow)),]

ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=N,y=pow)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.8,col='red') + 
  ylab('Power') + 
  xlab("N") +
  ggtitle('Power') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(min(Ns),max(Ns),10))

ggplot(data=df) + geom_point(aes(x=N,y=coverage)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.90,col='red') + 
  ylab('Coverage') + 
  xlab("N") +
  ggtitle('Coverage') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(min(Ns),max(Ns),10))
```

[image]

I have edited the code to: Change the CI to agresti-coull and the level to 0.90%. Now the power plot looks like this:

[image]

On the basis of this, is it correct to say that: If the true probability of the event is 93%, I need a sample size of approximately 100. Then I will have a probability of 80% of accepting that the probability is greater then 85%.

Comment: FYI, your code doesn't work; 'width' and 'ests' are not defined.

Comment: Thank you. I have now edited the code. I was looking at the estimates and the width of the intervals, so see if that provides a clue, but then took it out so as not to obfuscate the issue.

Comment: This pattern is due to the discreteness of the binomial distribution. It's common to see such a pattern when dealing with binomial confidence intervals, see, for example the graphs in the paper of [Brown et al (2002)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-2/Interval-Estimation-for-a-Binomial-Proportion/10.1214/ss/1009213286.full). The section 2.1 in the paper discusses the oscillation pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and the very useful link.

Comment: If I want my sample size to be such that I can be 95% sure that the confidence interval has a lower limit greater than 0.85: Would I be right that I need to calculate a 90% CI?